# MySQL compare column from one table to another column in another database's table

Tags: mysql

Here is some pseudo code of what i am trying to accomplish with an SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE id=[column in another database]
```

How can I compare another database's column value to the one I am running the query on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE id=[SELECT id FROM DATABASE.TABLE WHERE other conditional code here];
```

Comment: How am i to do this without the brackets?

Comment: You haven't given enough information as to what you are trying to do and we do not know your table structures. But an example that would work is: "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM DATABASE2.TABLENAME);"

Answer (score 0):

Sql Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] 
WHERE id=[SELECT column FROM another table]
```

Comment: But its another table in another database.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join between the two tables like:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.*
FROM db1.table1 t1 INNER JOIN db2.table2 t2
ON t1.id=t2.id
```